# How to combine listener class and view class? | Android

Tags: java, android, onclick, imageview, onclicklistener

I'm trying to capture all about an ImageView in a single class.
1st of all, I tried

```
class myImage extends ImageView{ 
    ...
 }
```

to capture properties of `ImageView`. It works.

Now, to integrate the Listeners as well, I tried

```
class myImage extends ImageView implements ImageView.OnClickListener{
    ...
    @Override
    public void onClick(){
         ....
    }
}
```

This doesn't work! What is my mistake?

I tried `setOnClickListener(myListener);`, it works. But when an instance is made, the onClick here cannot be the method of the instance itself.

> **PS:** The inspiration for integrating View and Listener is so that, the `onClick()` method can have all the privileges of the class method (Access members of the `myImage` instance).

Comment: This is not proper way to do this . What if you use `myImage` in multiple screens . Just follow the conventional approach.

Comment: This would be really easy if you used android databinding

Comment: I strongly feel that `onClick()`, which have a very close relation to `ImageView` (at least in my case) should be a 'property' of view itself. That can make my code a lot simpler.

Comment: If you want it simpler then use databinding .

Comment: Databinding can only bind data, what about methods then?

Comment: Let me post an example where i bind methods

Comment: Turns out i'm using kotlin to accomplish that, sorry

Comment: @IzzoObella, could you please post a Java implementation as one of the answers? (for binding methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```
     public class MyImageView extends ImageView implements View.OnClickListener {

    setOnClickListener(this);

     @Override
     public void onClick(){
     //your click listener
    }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

So first of all i implement a BindingAdapter function within any class, preferably one with your Global or frequently accessed functions

*BindingAdapter.java*

```
 @BindingAdapter({"imageClick"})
   public static final void imageClick(@NotNull View view) {
      // Do your onclick stuff here
   }
```

*ClickInterface.java*

```
public interface ImageClick{
  void onImageClicked()
}
```

Then you can do this in your xml

*fragment_item.xml*

```
<layout>
...
<ImageView
...
app:imageClick="@{(v)->handler.onImageClicked()}"
/>
</layout>
```

**Method 2**

If the click function is in fragment or activity that inflates the view then you can use this.
*Fragment.java*

```
...
public void ImageClick(View view){
 // Do your click stuff
}
...
```

*fragment.xml*

```
<layout>
<data>
<variable
name="fragment"
type="....Fragment"/>
</data>

...
<ImageView
...
android:onClick="@{fragment::ImageClick}"
/>
...
</layout>
```